# Need to delete a directory with name '~' created accidentally

Tags: directory, filenames, rm

I don't remember exactly how this directory got created. It's name is `~`, the alternative we all use for `home diretory`. I also see a sticky bit attached with this directory. How shall I delete it? I fear running a normal rmdir would delete all the files from the home directory recursively. Here are the details :

```
mtk4@laptop:~/temp$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-t 2 mtk4 mtk4 4096 Oct 17 2011 ~
```

How shall I proceed?

Another question : What does the `total` number specify on the first line of output of `ls -l` ? '4' in this case. There is just 1 directory as shown(other than `.` and `..`).

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Also asked same question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), as it seems to be relavant on both sites.

Comment: `rmdir` isn't capable of recursive deletion - you need `rm` with the `-r` flag for that.

Comment: `rmdir \~` .....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just quote the directory. I use rmdir just to ensure you don't accidently delete your home directory.

```
rmdir "~"
```

For your other question (better to create a extra question for it) total means the total file size of the directory (sum of the file sizes in the output). 
If you use  `-h` it will show you the size in a human readable format.

`ls -lh`

Answer (score 5):

You can form the directory name in such a way so that the shell doesn't expand it.  mru's answer will work.  So will prepending "./" to it (i.e., indicating current directory), or specify the full path, e.g., `rmdir ./~`.

Answer (score 3):

Enter the tmp directory and enclose the `~` in quotes. It will not expand to your $HOME.

`rm -r "~"`

The "4" is the size of all files in the directory. If you perform `ls -lh`, it will print it in human readable format.

```
# ls -l                                                                               
total 1272
-rw-rw-r--. 1 me me  33222 May  8 18:02 untangle.dmp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 me me 426780 May  8 17:15 new.orig.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 me me 425195 May  8 15:40 repos.orig.dmp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 me me 407823 May  8 18:02 blah-untangle.dmp
# ls -lh                                                                              
total 1.3M
-rw-rw-r--. 1 me me  33K May  8 18:02 untangle.dmp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 me me 417K May  8 17:15 new.orig.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 me me 416K May  8 15:40 repos.orig.dmp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 me me 399K May  8 18:02 blah-untangle.dmp
```

Also, please [don't cross post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#cross-posting).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Double quotes worked. I didn't know about the cross-posting. Will be careful next time, to post only on the most relevant site. Also deleting the duplicate post of mine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Standard solution: `rm ./-`

Not-so-standard solution: `rm -- -`

Explanation: `rm` (and many other commands) takes strings starting `-` as options, not file names. By stating the name as `./-` the argument doesn't start `-` anymore, and is taken as a file name. Not-so-standard is that many programs (particularly GNU ones) recognize `--` as "end of options", so the lone `-` loses any optiony meaning, and must be a file name.

Comment: I think the question said the directory is called `~`, not `-`.